# Physical compatibility between US and UK layout keyboards

Tags: keyboard

I need to replace my Lenovo G570 keyboard. Is there a physical difference between the US layout and the UK layout? Would the US layout keyboard fit the laptop exactly as the UK layout keyboard? Is there anything I would need to do to use it once it is fitted?
Many thanks
Sue

Answer (score 0):

Most laptop keyboards can be swapped with a different regional layout for the same model, or even similar models.  To be 100% sure, you should call Lenovo's sales/parts and they would be able to give a definitive answer.  Refer to the manual that comes with the keyboard on how to change it.  Some laptop keyboards are easy to replace, others can require a lot of effort as they require opening the laptop and removing parts and screws.  If you arent comfortable doing that, buy your tech friend a beer, or take it to the local computer shop.

As for there being physical differences, yes there are.  UK regional keyboards not only have different character layouts, but the key sizes, placements, and shapes are slightly different from the US layout.  The differences are minor, but you will find yourself looking for characters and hitting the wrong keys for a short while.  It doesnt take long to overcome though.

After changing the keyboard physically, you need to tell Windows that it is a different keyboard. In Windows 7, click Start, then type "Region and Language" - it should pop up as you type.  Click on it and select the "Keyboards and Languages" tab.  Then click the "Change keyboards..." button.  Click "Add..." Find "English (United Kingdom)" and expand "Keyboard" and select "United Kingdom."